# What would be the difference in distance between earth and moon on supermoon night (14 November 2016)

Tags: earth, distances, the-moon

As we all know the usual distance between earth and moon is 384,400 km.
But i was thinking how much closer it will be on 14 November 2016, as it will be a supermoon, the brightest and biggest moon in 60 years.

Comment: This is really far too simple a question to be worth keeping in this site.

Comment: http://www.space.com/34660-closest-supermoon-full-moon-in-69-years-forecast.html

Comment: You may or may not find my https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/19043/how-can-the-next-supermoon-be-analytically-predicted/19052#19052 useful.

Answer (score 1):

Based on some information from this article

http://www.space.com/34515-supermoon-guide.html

The Nov 14 2016 supermooon's expected peak of full phase 
is on the morning ov Nov 14 at 8:52 AM EST

According to some quick calculations that I performed
using PyEphem

and assuming the moon would be viewed by an observer in NYC at 08:52AM EST

**0.00236372323707 AU** from observer
An AU is 1.5 * 10^km

**Edit: I needed a better precision for km to AU**

http://www.iau.org/static/resolutions/IAU2012_English.pdf

According to this, the AU can be more precisely defined as 
149 597 870 700  meters +/- 3 meters

0.00236372323707 * 149 597 870 700 =

**353 607 963.19 meters** or

**~ 353,608 km from earth**

here is a quick run through of the inputs I used for the program

```
>>> moon = ephem.Moon()
>>> nyc = ephem.Observer()
>>> nyc.long, nyc.lat = '-74.0059', '40.7127'
>>> nyc.date = '2016/11/14 08:52:00'
>>> moon.compute(nyc)
>>> print moon.earth_distance

    0.00236372323707
```

Learn more about PyEphem package here
http://rhodesmill.org/pyephem/index.html

Note I'm just an amateur and these calculations might not take in certain critical factors. I'm uncertain if PyEphems earth_distance property calculates distance to the moon or the moon's center.

If it does calculate distance to the center of the moon this number could be about ~1700 km smaller.

Given your figure of 384,400 km average, this would put the moon just under

**~30 792 km closer to the earth or about 91.98 % of it's normal distance**

Comment: How do you multiply by something with two significant figure precision to get something quoted to 7 significant figures?

Comment: Good point. I need a better figure for KM per AU

Answer (score 1):

From where I am on Vancouver Island,  western Canada, it will be around 356,500 km. [image: screenshot]

Comment: In this case, it would be a good idea stating your source.